# Pull out href's with beautifulsoup attrs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying something new with pulling out all the href's in the `a` tags. It isn't pulling out the hrefs though and cant figure out why.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for href in soup.findAll('a'):
    h = href.attrs['href']
    print(h)
```

Comment: Look at your `page.text` variable and ensure those elements actually exist. Most websites these days dynamically load content after page load, so a simple GET request to the page won't pick up the dynamic data

Comment: They are all there when I print the soup variable

Comment: So is BS actually finding `a` tags?  Ie, does your for loop actually have something to loop over?

Comment: Yes. It is finding the `a` tags and prints them all out in the `for` loop but when I try to extract the hrefs, I get an error.   `h = href.attrs['href']
KeyError: 'href'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the key exists, since it may also not exist an href between `<a>` tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'href' in a.attrs:
        print(a.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: Nice! That does it.